# Apache .htaccess and Zend Rewrite conflict with Redirect

Tags: zend-framework, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, conflict

I'm using this .htaccess code to redirect the old domain to the new domain:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.domain.eu(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.domain.be/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works, also for subdirectories. But in the directory /project, there's a Zend project with the following .htaccess:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When I go that directory on the old domain, the redirect doesn't work. So I'm guessing these 2 .htaccess files conflict eachother. Does anyone have an idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these 2 rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.domain.eu(.*)
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.domain.be/$1 [R=301,L]
```

to `/project`'s .htaccess as well.

> When an URI request is made, the `.htaccess` in the lower most directory with .htaccess is looked for & used.

Courtesy: @`TerryE`.

i.e.

- `/folder/folder1/folder2` is the requested URI, and lets say all of them has `.htaccess` then, folder2's `.htaccess` will only be used.
- `/folder/folder1/folder2` is the requested URI, and lets say only `folder1` has a `.htaccess` then, folder1's `.htaccess` will only be used.

---

So, do this:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} test.domain.eu
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.domain.be/project/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but now test.domain.eu/project redirects to test.domain.be